# OnMapReady is not being called/shown in fragmentContainerView

Tags: android, google-maps, kotlin

I'm new to Google Maps API, I have this problem that when I try to show the map on a fragmentContainerView it doesn't show the markers and doesn't zoom the camera but when I setContentView on the fragment itself it shows the markers zooms the camera.

> This just shows the map inside the fragmentContainerView without the markers and doesn't zoom, it basically just calls a map.

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map)
        supportActionBar?.hide()

        val mapFragment = supportFragmentManager
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map) as SupportMapFragment?
        mapFragment?.getMapAsync(this)
        
        fusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this)
    }
```

> Now this on the other hand shows the markers and zooms as well, but it replaces the whole activity view because of the setContentView.

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map)
        supportActionBar?.hide()

        binding = FragmentMapsBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        val mapFragment = supportFragmentManager
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map) as SupportMapFragment?
        mapFragment?.getMapAsync(this)

        fusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this)
    }
```

Please Help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The problem is that you're trying to use the Activity's FragmentManager, and you should be using the Fragment's child FragmentManager.
> Remove the onCreate() override in the Fragment, and add an onCreateView() Override where you inflate the layout.

```
  override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {

    binding = FragmentMapsBinding.inflate(inflate,R.layout.activity_map, 
              container, false)


    val mapFragment = childFragmentManager
        .findFragmentById(R.id.map) as SupportMapFragment?
    mapFragment?.getMapAsync(this)

    fusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this)
    
    return binding.root
}
```